# HTML5 Drag-Drop - How to know the difference between local files and clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

OK, so I have built a drag-n-drop system where javascript checks whether the files are, well, files, and not folders, pieces of text or hyperlinks. The problem is, javascript seems to not know the difference between files from clipboard and local files using the details from e.dataTransfer.

For example: I can drag an image directly from a website in the browser to the drag-n-drop area, and javascript will automatically treat it like it's a local file. Is there anyway I can prevent javascript from considering any sort of files other than local files?

Comment: What would be the point of this?

Comment: To build a "local files only" drag-n-drop system.

Comment: Right, but I don't see why. Why do you care where the file was from?

Comment: Because clipboard files are not compatible with a chunks-based resumable file upload system I've built.

Comment: Ah, then you should probably add that to the question along with what you tried and where you ran into a problem.